# Why is VS2019 still copying embedded resources to the output folder?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, embedded-resource

When i try to embed resources in a .NET Core Webservice project via `EmbeddedResource` in the `.csproj` file, these resources are also copied into the output folder, although i choose the option to NOT copy in the build action dropdown-menu.

The part where the resource is embedded looks like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\logging.json" />
</ItemGroup>
```

In another .NET Core project, which is a library, the resource gets embedded and won't be copied to the output directory.

There, the snippet looks like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <EmbeddedResource Include="LicenseText\*.txt" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Is there an explanation to this behaviour?

Comment: can you show a snippet of the part in your csproj where it sets your files to `EmbeddedResource`?

Comment: Sure, i've added snippets of both csproj files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue on my side. I checked the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-items?view=vs-2019#embeddedresource) about `EmbeddedResource` item, and the metadata introduced like this

> CopyToOutputDirectory Optional string. Determines whether to copy the file to the output directory. Values are: 1. Never. 2. Always. 3. PreserveNewest.

I tested by adding related metadata into `.csproj` file manually, but the issue remained.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\logging.json">
     <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory> 
  </EmbeddedResource>
</ItemGroup>
```

I think this should be a potential issue and I have reported it to Microsoft Developer Community, hope VS product team can fix it and share the insights. Here is the link: [Embedded Resources still copy to output directory even set `CopyToOutputDirectory` to Never](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/embedded-resources-still-copy-to-output-directory/1474603?from=email).

Comment: Thanks a ton! Seems to be only happening with ```Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web```.